# github syncing a fork with a local branch

Tags: git, github

I may have messed up my workflow with github - I noticed some issues with a repo and wanted to fix them. I cloned the repo (Github Desktop, Mac OS) and made the changes in XCode, I created a local branch to the repo after making the changes and committed the changes. I then tried to push the changes but had an error related to permissions.

I went to the github repo and forked it, now I have the fork in my github account and the local branch. I can't figure out how to merge my local branch changes into the fork without overwriting them (no changes made to the fork).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to:

1. Add a new `remote` repository pointing to your fork
2. Push your local changes to your `remote` fork

To add the new remote you'll have to type this in your repository folder:

`git remote add myfork {GIT_URL_OF_YOUR_FORK}`

After this you simply need to push your branch to your fork

`git push myfork {BRANCH_NAME_THAT_HAS_THE_LOCAL_CHANGES}`

This should be about it.

Comment: Thank you - I was able to make this work and the changes show up in the branch when done from the command line, but I still have an issue doing a publish from xcode or github desktop - it attempts to publish to the master repo. Is there a setting to specify the branch as the preferred target?

Comment: It doesn't seem you can add a remote, but can change the existing one: https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing/changing-a-remote-s-url-from-github-desktop/